# Proof that set is a convex set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

> Let $\displaystyle W(A):=\left\{ \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}: x\in C^{n} \right\}$ and $A\in C^{n} $ so that $ A^{*}A=AA^{*} $

$A^{*} $ is the complex conjugate of $A^T$ (the transpose of a)
 (See: [Conjugate Transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose))

I need to proof that $W(A)$ is a convex set. I just know the definition of a convex set which (as far as I know) is that if $a,b \in W(A) $ then every point on the line from a to b is in $W(A)$.

Comment: What is a gersgorin set?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x} = \left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)^* A \left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)$

Comment: still dont get it. How does it help that $A$ is a normal matrix ?